# Интернационализация в QML

Tags: qt, qml

```
QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

QTranslator ruLang;
if (ruLang.load(":/Application_ru"))
     qDebug() << "we're good..............";
app.installTranslator(&ruLang);

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

return app.exec();
```

Файл переводчика прогружается вроде бы нормально ибо в дебаг выдает сообщение что все норм. Но приложение запускается без перевода. В чем могут быть причины?

Comment: qsTr("...") для пользовательских строк используешь в qml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено! Проблема была в другом, - засунул центральный кусок кода в `if else` где объект `QTranslator` удалялся после завершения блока